# Urldecode bug: after adding a simple product to shopping cart on search page and redirect to current page

Tags: magento-1.7, url

With Magento 1.7.0.2 If you are on catalog search page and list mode is on.

```
Url:  http://127.0.0.1/magento_test/catalogsearch/result/index/?mode=list&q=camera
```

And redirect to current page after adding product to cart is Active in admin panel.

If you try to add simple product to cart, product added to cart successful but redirection URL is not decoded properly

```
All ‘&’ replaced by ‘&amp;’ and result in breaking search result...

Result URL: http://127.0.0.1/magento_test/catalogsearch/result/index/?mode=list&amp;q=camera
```

I know this file is responsible, In this fle app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Abstract.php `public function escapeUrl($data)`

It use htmlspecialchars function of php which replace & with `&amp;`

So if there is any solution for this, can it safe to remove `htmlspecialchars` from this function?

This bug is resolved or not?

For what I do now to fix this issue is I have ovewrite my Cartcontroller `_goBack` function which call `this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);` so for now I have put my custom url redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this observer to your config.xml:

```
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
            <observers>
                <unique_observer_node>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>My_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkoutCartAddProductComplete</method>
                </unique_observer_node>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
    </events>
```

/app/code/community/My/Modul/Model/Observer.php

```
function checkoutCartAddProductComplete($observer)
    {
        /**
         * @var $request Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http
         */
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/cart/redirect_to_cart')) {
            $request     = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
            $referrerUrl = $request->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
            if ($url = $request->getParam(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::PARAM_NAME_REFERER_URL)) {
                $referrerUrl = $url;
            }
            if ($url = $request->getParam(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL)) {
                $referrerUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
            }
            if ($url = $request->getParam(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
                $referrerUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
            }
            if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($referrerUrl)) {
                $referrerUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
            }
            $request->setParam('return_url', $referrerUrl);
        }
    }

    protected function _isUrlInternal($url)
    {
        if (strpos($url, 'http') !== false) {
            if ((strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl()) === 0)
                || (strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, true)) === 0)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I know the solution but I am asking if this bug was known? or it was resolved or not?

Comment: So if there is any solution for this, can it safe to remove `htmlspecialchars` from this function? I gave solution without rewrite controller